# How to set input accessory view's constraint above app-switcher/closer bar?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm having difficulties constraining my `inputAccessoryView` above the bottom safe area for iPhoneX screens (and other notch devices). I have a `UICollectionViewController` whose `inputAccessoryView` is a `UIView` that contains a `UITextView`, and 2 `UIButtons`. Basically the layout is for a chat app. When I run my current code, the `inputAccessoryView` does not appear above the safe area on the bottom of the screen. It's currently anchored to the bottom of the screen. Attached screenshot.
[image]

As you can see, the bottom app-switcher/closer bar overlaps my inputAccessoryView. I'd like to have the inputAccessoryView to be above the said bar.

Here's my current code (related to constraints):

```
class NewMessagesViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    private lazy var inputTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.placeholder = "Enter message"
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.delegate = self
        return textField
    }()
    private lazy var inputContainerView: UIView = {
        let margin = view.layoutMarginsGuide
        let safeArea = view.safeAreaInsets

        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50)
        containerView.backgroundColor = .white

        let uploadImageView = UIImageView()
        uploadImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        uploadImageView.image = UIImage(named: "image")
        uploadImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        uploadImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleUploadTap)))
        containerView.addSubview(uploadImageView)
        uploadImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        uploadImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        uploadImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
        uploadImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true

        let sendButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        sendButton.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
        sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendText), for: .touchUpInside)
        containerView.addSubview(sendButton)
        // x,y,w,h
        sendButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        sendButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        sendButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        sendButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        containerView.addSubview(self.inputTextField)
        self.inputTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uploadImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        self.inputTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        self.inputTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.inputTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        let separatorLineView = UIView()
        separatorLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 220, green: 220, blue: 220)
        separatorLineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(separatorLineView)
        separatorLineView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        separatorLineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        separatorLineView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        separatorLineView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

        return containerView
    }()

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        get {
            return inputContainerView
        }
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.title =  ticket.subject

        collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
    }
}
```

I've tried constraining the `UITextField and UIButton's` bottom anchor constraint to equal `view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor` in `viewDidLoad()` but that just made my app crash with error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x28204dac0 "UIImageView:0x107417780.bottom"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x2820270c0 "UILayoutGuide:0x280c8cb60'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.bottom"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

Appreciate if anyone can provide a code snippet of how to properly constrain the inputAccessoryView above the app switcher/closer bar.

Comment: Why not just make input view taller when the safe area bottom is inset?

Comment: can you please add the storyboard screenshot of  NewMessagesViewController.

Comment: @SGDev I didn't use storyboard for NewMessagesViewController

Answer (score 1):

Set CollectionView Bottom constraints with SafeArea, This will solved your problems.